# How to show django form in django template?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

I am trying to create a form using django and css.

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .forms import ContactForm

def home(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ContactForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            pass
        else:
            form = ContactForm()
        return render(request, 'home.html', {'form':form})
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms

class ContactForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField(max_length = 30)
    email = forms.EmailField(max_length = 254)
    message = forms.CharField(max_length = 2000, widget = forms.Textarea(),help_text = "Write Your Message here")

def clean(self):
    cleaned_data = super(ContactForm, self).clean()
    name = cleaned_data.get('name')
    email = cleaned_data.get('email')
    message = cleaned_data.get('message')
    if not name and not email and not message:
        raise forms.ValidationError('You have to write something!')
```

When I try to add the form to my html page like the following it doesn't show up. Just the button shows up, no form fields -

```
{% extends 'store/main.html' %}
{% load static %}

{% block content %}
<h3>Store</h3>

<form method = "post" novalidate>
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}
    <button type='submit'>Submit</button>
</form>
{% endblock content %}
```

If I do css form instead it obviously show up the way it should.

```
{% extends 'store/main.html' %}
{% load static %}

{% block content %}
<h3>Store</h3>
<form>
    <label for="fname">First Name</label>
    <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname">
    <button type='submit'>Submit</button>
  </form>
{% endblock content %}
```

So I decided to add the form fields individually to the css form. Where does the {{form.name}} or {{form.email}} tag go?

EDIT:
Hey Vivek, the contact form code is this -

```html
class ContactForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField(max_length = 30)
    email = forms.EmailField(max_length = 254)
    message = forms.CharField(max_length = 2000, widget = forms.Textarea(),help_text = "Write Your Message here")
```

The html template looks like this-

```html
{% extends 'store/main.html' %}
{% load static %}
{% block content %}

<h3>Store</h3>


<form method = "post" novalidate>
  {% csrf_token %}
  <label class="float-left" for="name">Name</label>
  {{ form.name }}
    <button type='submit'>Submit</button>
  </form>

  

{% endblock content %}
```

Thanks for any input.

Answer (score 0):

Accessing form fields individually will make you to render the form errors individually as well. `{{form}}` encapsulates everything:- Form fields , errors, non_field_errors..So if you have to access the fields individually do not forget to add the form errors.

I have written a sample code which will server the purpose.

```
    {% csrf_token %}
     {% if form.errors %}
  <div class="alert alert-danger"  style="text-align:left">
    <ul>
    {% for field in form %}
        {% for error in field.errors %}

                <li><strong>{{ error|escape }}</strong></li>

        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
    {% for error in form.non_field_errors %}

            <li><strong>{{ error|escape }}</strong></li>

    {% endfor %}
      </ul>
    </div>
{% endif %}
   <div class="form-row">
        <div class="col-md-4  mb-3">
            <label class="float-left" for="id_name">Name</label>
      {{ form.name }}
        </div>
    <div class="col-md-8 mb-3">
      <label class="float-left" for="id_email">Email ID</label>
      {{ form.email }}
    </div>
  </div>
     <br>

   <input type="submit"  class="btn btn-primary" value="Pay" id="submit">

  </form>
```

Comment: Thank you Vivek. Your explanation and code make sense but it is not working on my end. The texts and button shows but form field don't. I will try to add a picture to my main post so you know how it looks. Thanks.

Comment: Can u also show the code you have tried after what i sent u and you code for ContactForm()

Comment: Just added those codes in the main post. Thank you.